# Squid option equivilents in nginx

Tags: nginx, squid

I am trying to move some caching over to nginx from squid and I'm having some issues replicating some options.

I have these options on one of my squid patterns `ignore-reload ignore-no-store override-expire override-lastmod ignore-must-revalidate` and I can't seem to get it working on nginx. The options I have at the moment are `proxy_ignore_headers Expires Cache-Control X-Accel-Expires;` but it isn't saving things to my cache.

Comment: Share Nginx conf you have even not working, it helps to solve your problem quicker. Be aware that Nginx caches only cookie-less response from backend, so strip cookies like: *proxy_hide_header      "Set-Cookie";   proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";*